# How do you append a large text file in a textBrowser in PyQt without freezing the GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to display a log file in a dialogue with three buttons.I can append each line to the textBrowser with the following code, but when I try to append the whole text the GUI freezes.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import os 
import sys
import time
import UI_logs

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):

        #Reading and appending the whole text
#         logs = open('logs.txt', 'r').read()
#         self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)'), str(logs))


        #Reading and appending line by line
        logs = open('logs.txt', 'r').readlines()
        for line in logs:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)'), str(line))
            time.sleep(0.1)
        self.terminate()


class Logs(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Logs, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = UI_logs.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.load_logs()

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.clear_logs)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_4, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.load_logs)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.export)

    def display_logs(self, text):
        self.ui.textBrowser.append(text)
        self.ui.textBrowser.update()
        self.ui.textBrowser.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)

    def load_logs(self):
        self.workThread = WorkThread()
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.workThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("update(QString)"), self.display_logs)
        self.workThread.start()

    def clear_logs(self):
        try:
            os.remove('logs.txt')
            self.ui.textBrowser.clear()
            info_msg = "Your logs file has been deleted."
            info_reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(None, 'Logs Notification', info_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)     

        except:
            info_msg = "Your logs file can not be deleted."
            info_reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(None, 'Logs Notification', info_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)

    def export(self):
        log_text = self.ui.textBrowser.toPlainText()
        if log_text:
            filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'Export logs as',
                                                          '.', 'Text Documents (*.txt)')
            if filename:
                fname = open(filename, 'w')
                fname.write(log_text)
                fname.close()
                info_msg = "Your logs file has been exported successfully."
                info_reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(None, 'Logs Notification', info_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)            
        else:
            warning_title = 'Export Warning'
            warning_text = 'There is nothing in the logs to export.'
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(None, warning_title,
                                      warning_text,  QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')
window = Logs()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with one of those 3 commented lines:

```
 logs = open('logs.txt', 'r').read()
 #logs = logs.encode('utf-8')
 #logs = QString(logs)
 #logs = unicode(QString(logs))
 self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)'), str(logs))
```

also, try them without converting `logs` to string:

```
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)'), logs)
```

I don't have `import UI_logs` so I can't test it, but one of those should work...

Comment: Please confirm if any of given suggestions solves your problem.